# Warning: Attempt to present Tutorial_para_app.incialViewController on Tutorial_para_app.ViewControlle whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want that when the user is logged, appears a view controller, and if he is not logged, i want to have another view controller...Basicly i want to change the initial view controller when the user is logged. But when i try what i'm doing, i get the error that appears in the title.

I searched this ask and i tried the answers, but it doesn't work for me..

Here is what i have..

```
 let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if defaults.boolForKey("FirstLaunch") {

        let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Normal") as UIViewController

        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else {


defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "FirstLaunch")
        defaults.synchronize()

    }
```

I also tried to put this...

```
let top:UIViewController = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController)!

        top.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But doesn't fix the problem. 
All of this code is in the storyboard of my ViewController.swift

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from? I.e. is it from within viewDidLoad? If so, try moving it to viewDidAPpear. or

Comment: I tried, and i get this error..
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <Tutorial_para_app.ViewController: 0x7fa171527f60>.'
How can i solve it???

Comment: You can't present a view controller from another view controller who's view isn't in the window hierarchy. When a view controller is loaded, the view only exists in memory, and is not 100% guaranteed to be added to the window until `viewDidAppear`. If you want to modify the loading view controller, I'd suggest modifying the windows `rootViewController` from the App Delegate on launch.

Comment: Do you know how can i do it in the app delegate, so if the user is running the app for the first time, he see a view controller, but if he is not, he see another view controller...
Maybe changing the initialViewController... but i'm not sure how to implement it and if it's gonna work

Comment: Just google for something like programmatically set initial view controller, or switch initial view controller etc. to get plenty and plenty of past questions on exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

To modify the windows root view controller when launching the app you can do the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    BOOL firstRun = <However you figure out if it's the apps first run>

    if(firstRun){
        self.window.rootViewController = <Load your first run controller from storyboard or xib>
    } else {
        self.window.rootViewController = <Load your normal controller from storyboard or xib>
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    ...

    return YES;
}
```

This will swap the window's root view controller when the app loads depending in whether or not it's the first run.

If you don't know how to load a view controller from a storyboard or xib, do a quick search. There are plenty of examples of how to do it.